# Как добавить файл в определенную папку git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

У меня есть папка css и мне нужно закинуть туда стили, если просто закинуть то он появится в коренной папке, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

```
git add style.css
git commin -am "Styles"
git push
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Git* не осуществляет файловые операции. Вы должны самостоятельно скопировать/создать файл в папке `css/style.css`, а затем добавить как у вас в примере.

```
git add css/style.css --force
```

`--force` - параметр принудительного добавления, если папка или файл попадают под *gitignore*.